# Why wont the "width" and "height" CSS properties affect my paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I am styling my `<p>` tag to have a certain size, but when I use

```html
<style>
p {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
```

or

```html
<style>
font {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
```

neither of them worked, but it worked when I resized `<h1>` and `<h2>`. When I looked this up; None of them pertained to text, only iframes, or div(s).

I have tried making them different sizes, but they appear the same. I tried checking the console for errors, but there were none.
Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(25, 45, 35);
}

p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<font>
  <b>
    Code will be represented with:
    <br/>
    <p style="color:white;">CODE</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:goldenrod;">KEYWORD</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:yellow;">"Strings"</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:magenta;">Numbers / Boolean</p>
  </b>
</font>
<br/>
```

I expected the `<p>` tag to be resized like `<h1>` and `<h2>`, but it wasn't, why?

Comment: In case you are working with HTML5, `font` tag is not supported in it. You should use CSS instead.

Comment: Tags with `display: inline` ignore width and height. [More info.](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193x/lectures/05/block-inline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Phix, you were making `<p>` tag as inline. instead in css make it to `display: inline-block`

```css
body {
  background: rgb(25, 45, 35);
}

p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<font>
  <b>
    Code will be represented with:
    <br/>
    <p style="color:white;">CODE</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:goldenrod;">KEYWORD</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:yellow;">"Strings"</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="color:magenta;">Numbers / Boolean</p>
  </b>
</font>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know alot about the differences between each option in CSS. and for some reason VS Code stopped providing CSS / HTML help when editing for some reason, if you know the answer to that, let me know! But thanks again.